# Prevent zero in nested ordered list when using css counters

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I am styling an HTML nested ordered list (numbered).
I am trying to achieve same layout as MS Word has usually when you press Tab before the numbered list item. Ex:

```
1. Item at top
1.1.1.1. Item at middle
2. Item at bottom
```

For now I have the following CSS which sets `1.0.0.1` for the `Item at middle`.
Is there any way to fix that with CSS and without changing the HTML?

```css
ol { counter-reset: itemCounter; padding-left: 0 }
ol li { list-style: none; }
ol li:not(:has(ol)):before {
    content: counters(itemCounter, ".") ". ";
    counter-increment: itemCounter;
}
```

```html
<ol>
   <li>Item at top</li>
   <li>
      <ol>
         <li>
            <ol>
               <li>
                  <ol>
                     <li>Item at middle</li>
                  </ol>
               </li>
            </ol>
         </li>
      </ol>
   </li>
   <li>Item at bottom</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Just a note: your code is not working on Firefox (no numbers at all), probably because of `:has`?

Comment: Feels like the wrong place to do this re: CSS but my opinion counts 0 here.  I always question the use of these tags when you set `list-style: none;` - why not use actual tags designed to be used and not have to force the padding on the left etc.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss those tag have semantic meaning and also some accessibility feature. You have to use them but in most of the time we want them to look different from the default behavior

Comment: Part of the problem is that the first `1` of the second line should already be a `2`, if you were really counting this on the top `li` level. (And the `2` on the next line should be a `3`.) But you apparently want to count the first and third top-level `li` only, and "leave out" the second one(?).

Comment: @TemaniAfif  Fair point there on the semantic meaning and actually one of my challenges with use of `<i>` I see in use/hijacked just because it is "shorter" than `<span>` (not part of THIS question to be clear)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I am not using actual tags because the tree is different from what HTML supposes to be nested lists. To use actual tags I will have to modify html so that `Item at middle` will be within the first `li` tag

Comment: @CBroe I have `3` `ol` tags in the second direct `li` of the root. Which means I am adding three sections to counter. First item should be number `1`. So root+3 sections should be `1.1.1.1`

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you have _three_ `li` in the top-level `ol` - which would normally count as 1, 2, 3, but you apparently want them "counted" as 1, 1, 2.

Comment: @CBroe well these days we see a lot of proofs that _nomal_ is different  I refer to MS Word which provides expected by me behavior for last several decades

Comment: @AlexeyVictorov I don't thik that MS Word uses a internal structure where the second element is skipped from the count if it has content, I would bet the contrary actually. I think CBroe suggests that you use the wrong structure to represent what you want. If you introduce a new children to an element, it should be inside, not after, it's just logic, and will solve the compatibility problem of using `not(:has(ol))`

Comment: @Kaddath I totally agree. The intended way of showing nested lists in HTML is different from the tree I have. I understand that the right path would be - aligning the tree with HTML standard. I was wondering if the expected numbering could be achieved without changing the HTML, just with the CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work as you need it to:

```css
ol { counter-reset: itemCounter; padding-left: 0 }
ol li { list-style: none; }
ol li:not(:has(ol)):before {
    content: counters(itemCounter, ".") ". ";
    counter-increment: itemCounter;
}

ol>li:has(ol) {
  counter-increment: itemCounter 0;
}

ol>li ol li:has(ol) {
  counter-increment: itemCounter 1;
}
```

```html
<ol>
   <li>Item at top</li>
   <li>
      <ol>
         <li>
            <ol>
               <li>
                  <ol>
                     <li>Item at middle</li>
                     <li>Item at middle</li>
                  </ol>
               </li>
            </ol>
         </li>
         <!-- a few li for testing  -->
         <li>
            <ol>
               <li>
                  <ol>
                     <li>Item at middle</li>
                  </ol>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <ol>
                     <li>Item at middle</li>
                     <li>Item at middle</li>
                  </ol>
               </li>
            </ol>
         </li>
      </ol>
   </li>
   <li>Item at bottom</li>
</ol>
```